# Preencher lista e finalizar laço python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, loop, matriz

Preciso de ajuda em um problema que me pede para preencher ir adicionando dados a uma lista até que seja declarado 'fim'.

```
E=[]
i=0
E.append(input('Nome do elemento?'))
while (i!=fim):
  E.append(input('Nome do elemento?'))
  if i == fim:
    break
```

Fiz esse código, mas não consigo acionar o break para sair do laço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu exemplo existem alguns erros:

1. fim não está como string
2. você está comparando fim com uma variável que contem um número inteiro
3. while(!=fim) já indica se você digitar 'fim' no input ele vai fazer o break automaticamente sem você precisar fazer um if pra isso. Mas aqui o fim também não é uma string.

```
E=[]

i = input('Nome do elemento: ')
while (i != 'fim'):
    i = input('Nome do elemento: ')
    E.append(i)

print(E)
```

Comment: Consegui resolver usando sua solução como base(o problema envolvia mais coisas). Muito obrigado!

Comment: Por nada! abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer adicionar nomes dentro de uma lista até decidir `parar`. Para isso, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo:

```
cont = 0
elementos = list()
while True:
    cont += 1
    elementos.append(input(f'Nome do {cont}º elemento: '))

    resp = input('Fim [S/N]? ').upper()
    while (len(resp) != 1) or (resp not in 'SN'):
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas "S" ou "N"!\033[m')
        resp = input('Fim [S/N]? ').upper()
    if resp == 'N':
        print(f'\033[32mA lista formada foi: {elementos}\033[m')
        break
```

Observe que quando executamos o seguinte algoritmo recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Nome do 1º elemento:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o nome e pressionar `Enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a seguinte mensagem; `Fim [S/N]?` . Se desejarmos continuar basta digitar `S` e pressionar `enter`. Então o algoritmo irá solicitar o próximo nome e, assim por diante.

Agora, se desejarmos encerrar, basta digitar `N` e pressionar `enter`. Neste momento o algoritmo exibirá a lista formada por todos os elementos anteriormente digitados e, em seguida, encerrará a sua execução.